# Band unfolding for magnetic systems

Tags: band-structure, magnetism, transition-metals

I'm trying to study the electronic structure of a 1D antiferromagnetic (in which the spin is associated with copper atoms) system, via spin-polarized calculations.

The unit cell dimensions are provided below (in Angstroms and degrees):

```
_cell_length_a                         9.043546
_cell_length_b                         9.043546
_cell_length_c                         13.972318
_cell_angle_alpha                      106.841789
_cell_angle_beta                       106.841789
_cell_angle_gamma                      41.484879
_cell_volume                           719.729328
```

**So is it necessary to perform band unfolding if I'm taking into account the magnetic unit cell** which consists of two primitive unit cells (one with a spin-up state associated with the Cu atom it
contains and the other with a Cu atom in the spin-down state)?

Comment: What you want to obtain from band unfolding? Seems your simulation cell is not so large in real space then you will obtain enough information in $k$-space.

Comment: @Jack Hi!. I've updated the question with the cell dimensions. So is the cell small enough in real space so that I won't risk losing information in k space?

Comment: Hi @Jack it's been more than 2 months since Atom replied to your question, was it helpful at all for attempting an answer here?

Comment: @Jack do you think you know enough about this topic to help attempt writing an answer?

Comment: @NikeDattani Its also been several months since Atom has logged in. If Jack can provide an answer with the current information, that would be good, but otherwise I can close it until Atom returns.

Comment: @NikeDattani For me, this question is not well-defined, so I can not post an answer.